# Difference of character of group vs character of representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm a little bit confused by the difference of a character of a group and a character of a representation

as I know: A character of a group is $\chi \in Hom(G, U(1))$ which form a group

and a  character of a representation $\rho \in Hom(G , GL(V)) $ as $ \chi_\rho(g) = Tr(\rho(g))$

since $Tr(AB) \neq Tr(A)Tr(B)$ a character of a representation can't be a homomorphism

but is there a special case where $\chi_{group} = \chi_{rep}$?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the general definition of a character of a group $G$ over field $k$ is that it is a group homomorphism $\chi:G\to k^*$ to the multiplicative group of $k$. If we consider $k=\mathbb{C}$ the field of complex numbers and $G$ finite (or periodic) then indeed the image $\chi(G)$ has to be contained in $S^1$ which is isomorphic to $U(1)$. And so these definitions coincide for $\mathbb{C}$ and finite $G$. Which I assume is the case.

> since $Tr(AB) \neq Tr(A)Tr(B)$ a character of a representation can't be a homomorphism

Unless $V$ is one-dimensional. In that particular case $V\simeq\mathbb{C}$ as a linear space, $GL(V)\simeq\mathbb{C}^*$, $Tr(X)=X$ (and thus $Tr(AB)=Tr(A)Tr(B)$ trivially), and we are back at the first definition.

Thus a character of a group is a special case of representation character for one-dimensional representation.